# Problem related to the polynomial ring of several variables.

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains, polynomial-rings

I have to show that :

1. $\mathbb Z[x,y]/<y+1>$ is an unique factorisation domain.
2. $\mathbb C[x,y]/<x^2+1,y>$ is neither a prime nor a  maximal ideal.

I hardly understand the polynomial rings of several variables and that's why I asked  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416350/understanding-polynomial-rings-of-several-variables) , but unfortunately I didn't get any response from anyone. That's why I am posting my specific problems about the polynomial rings.

Any helpful response will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand the question. If 1. refers to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y+1)$, I think it is UFD. To see this, you can try to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y+1)\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]$. If 2. refers to the ideal $(x^2+1,y)$, show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+1, y)$ has zero divisors. You can either find a simple description of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+1, y)$ or show directly an example of a zero divisor. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, your reference for the 2 rings are right.

Comment: Actually I am stuck at finding any simple description of the ring in case 2.

Comment: The idea is that the elements in the ideal $(x^2+1,y)$ are the same as null. So write the polynomial $p(x,y)=a_{0,0}+ a_{1,0}x+\cdots +a_{n,m}x^ny^m$ and remove the terms with "$y=0$", you are left with $p(x,y)=a_{0,0}+a_{1,0}x+\cdots +a_{k,0}x^k$. In the same way, "$x^2=-1$", so you get $p(x,y)=a_{0,0}'+a_{1,0}'x$. As zero divisors you have $(x+i)(x-i)=x^2+1=0$ for $x+i\neq 0$ and $x-i\neq 0$. To make the argument rigorous, practice the isomorphism theorems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. $\mathbf Z[X,Y]/(Y+1)\simeq\mathbf (Z[X])[Y]/(Y+1)\simeq \mathbf Z[X]$.
2. $\begin{aligned}[t]\mathbf C[X,Y]/(X^2+1, Y)&\simeq\bigl(\mathbf C[X]/(X^2+1)\bigr)[Y]/(Y)\simeq\mathbf C[X]/(X^2+1)\\&\simeq\mathbf C[X]/(X+i)(X-i)\simeq\mathbf C\times\mathbf C.\end{aligned}$

Comment: Very useful hint ! I will be trying to prove this. @Bernard.

Comment: In the 2nd case how the first isomorphism is possible ? I am stuck there. Will you explain @Bernard

Comment: You have the third isomorphism theorem as an intermediate step: $\mathbf C[X,Y]/(X^2+1, Y)\simeq(\mathbf C[X,Y]/(X^2+1)\!\!\Bigm/\!\!(X^2+1,Y)/(X^2+1)$. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes ! Now it's clear ! Actually missed the 3rd Isomorphism theorem ! ..